# Pandas: Parsing / converting a column as date after importing from read_sql

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
from pandas.io import sql  
import sqlite3  
conn = sqlite3.connect('breakDownRecs.sqlite')  
query = "SELECT * FROM indRecs"  
df = sql.read_sql(query, con=conn)  #parse_dates=['DateDayId'])  
print(df)
```

I get (correctly) something like:

```
               DateID           Usr EventTypeM  DateDayID  DateMonthID
0      20151007221243        Noelle        LVL   20151007       201510
1      20151007225607         Morak        QST   20151007       201510
2      20151007225621   Austinpower        QST   20151007       201510
...
```

The question is how can I parse it so to become DateDayID column as a date, so to be indexed later?  If I provide:

```
df = sql.read_sql(query, con=conn, parse_dates=['DateDayID'])
```

It gives me

```
               DateID           Usr EventTypeM DateDayID  DateMonthID
0      20151007221243        Noelle        LVL       NaT       201510
1      20151007225607         Morak        QST       NaT       201510
...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter [`format`](http://strftime.org/):

```
df['DateID'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DateID, format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print df
               DateID     Usr EventTypeM DateDayID  DateMonthID
0 2015-10-07 22:12:43  Noelle        LVL       NaT       201510
1 2015-10-07 22:56:07   Morak        QST       NaT       201510
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df = sql.read_sql(query, con=conn, parse_dates=['DateID'])
```

or

```
df = sql.read_sql(query, con=conn, parse_dates={'DateID': {'format': '%Y-%m-%d'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

df.loc[:, 'DateID'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DateID)
```